# How to invoke a Gurilla Mux handler programmatically?

Tags: go, mux

I'm trying to invoke a Gurilla Mux handler programmatically in another handler function.  Simply calling that handler function won't work, because it uses `mux.Vars()`.  What I have at hand is a URL.  Therefore, I'm looking for a way to invoke that handler function just as if the user has visited that URL, and I want the response back to further process it.  Does anyone know a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't calling the function work? The data for `mux.Vars()` is stored in a global context that maps requests into the relevant data. As long as you pass the same request pointer into the handler, it will be able to access `mux.Vars()`.